# How to execute a callback only if previous observable returns specific value

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Suppose I have 3 functions each returning an observable. Each observable will emit only one value - `true` or `false`. I want to call them one after another only if the previous one returns `true`. Otherwise, I just want to return `false` and end the observable. How can I do that?

It would be quite easy with promises:

```
return fn1().then(fn2).then(fn3).catch((v)=>{return v})
```

As soon as any function in the chain rejects the promise with `false` no other promise callbacks will be called and the resolved promise value will be `false`. I'm looking for something similar with observables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `concatMap()` to execute async tasks in order and then `takeWhile()` to complete the stream if necessary:

```
fn1()
  .takeWhile(res => res)
  .concatMap(() => fn2())
  .takeWhile(res => res)
  .concatMap(() => fn3())
  .takeWhile(res => res)
  .subscribe(...)
```

Comment: thanks, do you think you could put up  some visual explanation?

Comment: `takeWhile` expect a callback function that accepts a parameter and has to return `true/false`. Since your logic is based just on the return value from the previous call you can simply return it right away. You could also write `takeWhile(Boolean)` but it might be a bit confusing.

Comment: yeah, thanks, i figured that out 10 seconds after I posted the comment so I removed it :) posted  another one

Comment: Have a look at the diagrams in the doc: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-takeWhile and http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatMap. I have no idea how I'd visualize nested Observables myself...

Comment: I've seen those, okay, never mind. Do you also maybe know how to access operators using global `Rx` object? This works `Rx.Observable.concat()` but is it the correct way? Suppose I don't use ES6 moduels

Comment: Only a few operators have a static form (`concat` is one of them). Have a look at the top section *"Static Method Summary"* at http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html

Comment: right, that is the question, how to access all other operators that are not on `Observable`. I could probably import them if I used ES6 modules, but if I don't then how?

Comment: You mean operators that aren't static?

Comment: Those that aren't available as static method need to be used somewhere in an Observable chain because it doesn't make sense to use them as static. For example what is `filter()`, `map()`, `do()`, `takeWhile()`, etc. supposed to do on their own when there's no preceding source Observable?